# Authetication error while deploying QFS

Tags: c++, qfs

Deploying 1 metaserver and 2 chunkserver, they are running on 3 boxes. While starting Metaserver server, I am getting the below error:

06-12-2017 21:05:48.331 ERROR - (ChunkServer.cc:1093) 192.168.75.135:40935 file system id mismatch
06-12-2017 21:05:48.331 ERROR - (ChunkServer.cc:886) chunk server  -1/192.168.75.135:40935 down reason: hello authentication error, cluster key, or md5sum mismatch socket error: 
06-12-2017 21:05:48.331 DEBUG - (ChunkServer.cc:438)  -1 ~ChunkServer 0x17cffb0 total: 1

The metaserver and chunkserver config file are like these：

```
#metaServer
metaServer.clientPort = 20000
metaServer.chunkServerPort = 20100
metaServer.rackPrefixes = 192.168.75.133 1 192.168.75.135 2 
metaServer.createEmptyFs = 1
metaServer.cpDir = /home/nevihs/qfsbase/meta/checkpoints
metaServer.logDir = /home/nevihs/qfsbase/meta/logs
metaServer.clusterKey = Qfs
metaServer.chunkServerMd5sums = 6d99c0d6fdac176eb3147c59276a6788

#chunkServer1
chunkServer.metaServer.hostname = 192.168.75.133
chunkServer.metaServer.port = 20100
chunkServer.clientPort = 21001
chunkServer.clusterKey = Qfs
chunkServer.chunkDir = /home/nevihs/qfsbase/chunk1/chunkdir11 

#chunkServer2
chunkServer.metaServer.hostname = 192.168.75.125
chunkServer.metaServer.port = 20100
chunkServer.clientPort = 21002
chunkServer.clusterKey = Qfs
chunkServer.chunkDir = /home/nevihs/qfsbase/chunk2/chunkdir21
```

As per the logs, It suggests three things.
1. file id mismatch: this is correct for me.
2. md5checksum mismatch
3. cluster key mismatch: This is consistent for my configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have pointed out. It seems md5checksum is not correct in metaServer configuration:

Can you regenerate it and retry again.
his md5 checksum of chunkserver binary  can be generated by running; "md5 "
 Modify metaserver configuration file. eg;
     metaServer.chunkServerMd5sums =

This is required here:
https://github.com/quantcast/qfs/blob/master/conf/MetaServer.prp

"A whitelist of space separated chunk server md5sums which are allowed to connect to the meta